Print to Brother IPP label printer which only supports image/urf
I'am implementing an .net API which should be able to print to network connected printers without having the drivers locally installed.
I successfully managed to print pdfs via IPP using this project SharpIpp
Now i have to check if it is possible to print to a Brother Label printer. I was not much suprised that it supports IPP. I was able to get its attributs. Unfortunately they say that supported formats are only application/octet-stream and image/urf.
I searched for a while for image conversion libraries, but none of them seems to offer conversion to urf which seems to be an proprietary Apple format. I found out that PWG-Raster is similar (subset) to URF-Raster and I wonder if I could just send that format instead.  Unfortunately also for this format i din't find any conversion libraries.
Does someone have a solution or hints for this?
Many thanks
Similitran
I searched for conversion libraries and and more information and did not find anything helpful.
